# cracking the coding interview, 11.5, search

Tags: c++

This is a coding problem in "Cracking the coding interview", I coded in C++
The problem is:

Given a sorted array of strings which is interspersed with empty strings, write a method to find the location of a given string.

Example: find `“ball”` in `[“at”, “”, “”, “”, “ball”, “”, “”, “car”, “”,“”, “dad”, “”, “”]` will return 4

Example: find `“ballcar”` in `[“at”, “”, “”, “”, “”, “ball”, “car”, “”, “”, “dad”, “”, “”]` will return `-1`

The following is my code and test cases:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int search(string s[], int left, int right, string x)
{
    if(left>right)
    {
        //cout<<"haha"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    int mid=(left+right)/2;
    if(s[mid]=="")
    {
        int t=mid;
        while(t<right && s[++t]==""){}
        if(t==right)
        {
            return search(s, left, mid-1, x);
        }
        else
        {
            mid=t;
        }
    }
    if(s[mid]==x)
    {
        //cout<<mid<<endl;
        return mid;
    }
    else if(s[mid]>x)
        search(s, left, mid-1, x);
    else
        search(s, mid+1, right, x);
}

int main()
{
    string s[27] = {
        "at", "", "", "", "ball", "", "", "car", "", "", "dad", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
    };
    cout<<search(s, 0, 26, "ball")<<endl;
    cout<<search(s, 0, 26, "car")<<endl;
    cout<<search(s, 0, 26, "dad")<<endl;
    cout<<search(s, 0, 26, "chunlei")<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

However, they always produce wield result, when I tried to cout before return, I can see the result is correct, but in the main function, the return value is always wrong. Can anyone help me see why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: don't understand your comment

Comment: If you can use `<algorithm>` then: http://ideone.com/qvvFpT can suffice. It uses `std::distance` and `std::find`

Comment: but why is my code wrong??

Comment: There is already an answer why.. You missed the return statements near the end of your search algorithm. Look near: `else if(s[mid]>x)`

Comment: @user3371909 If the array is sorted, all of the empty strings would be placed together.  If the empty strings are scattered throughout the array, then the array is not really sorted.  You are attempting to do a binary search on a non-sorted array (which won't work without special consideration for empty strings).  A sequential search that skips empty strings and stops when you've reached your target (or have passed where it would be in the array) would be more simple to implement.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to return your search results in your else and else if block.
For example replace

```
search(s, left, mid-1, x);
```

with

```
return search(s, left, mid-1, x);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the function should be declared at least as

```
int search( const string s[], int left, int right, const string &x );
```

Instead of comparisons similar as

```
if(s[mid]=="")
```

it is preferable to use

```
if ( s[mid].empty() )
```

Instead of the if statement with the followed while loop statement

```
if(s[mid]=="")
{
    int t=mid;
    while(t<right && s[++t]==""){}
```

it would be simpler to write

```
    int t = mid;
    while ( t < right && s[t].empty() ) ++t;
```

and after that do all other comparisons.

In thsi code snippet

```
else if(s[mid]>x)
    search(s, left, mid-1, x);
else
    search(s, mid+1, right, x);
```

you forgot to place return. There should be

```
   return s[mid] > x ? search(s, left, mid-1, x) : search(s, mid+1, right, x);
```

However this approach is wrong because all such functions that deal with arrays are declared as

int search( const string s[], int n, const string &x );

where n is the size of the array.

I could aggre with the declaration of the function with four parameters if you would use iterators instead of indexes.

Now try to write the same recursive function declared as

```
int search( const string s[], int n, const string &x );
```

and using only `operator <`. It is more difficult task.:)